# What is the syntax for array.select?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to use `Array.select` to separate out, and then delete, strings from a database that contain unwanted items. I get no errors but this does not seem to be working as hoped.

The relevant code is the last part:

```
totaltext = []
masterfacs = ''
nilfacs = ''

roomfacs_hash = {'lcd' => lcd2, 'wifi'=> wifi2, 'wired' => wired2, 'ac' => ac2}
roomfacs_hash.each do |fac, fac_array| 
  if roomfacs.include? (fac) 
    totaltext = (totaltext + fac_array)
    masterfacs = (masterfacs + fac + ' ')
  else
    nilfacs = (nilfacs + fac + ' ')
  end
end

finaltext = Array.new
text_to_delete = totaltext2.select {|sentences| sentences =~ /#{nilfacs}/i}
finaltext = totaltext2.delete (text_to_delete)
puts finaltext
```

Comment: Please take the time to indent your code.

Comment: Steenslag: yup, no errors when I run it
Meagar: Sorry! It's indented, but when I pasted and tried to post it told me "4 spaces over!" and I thought it meant for every line of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not working because [delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete) isn't a chainable method (the return value is the object you are trying to delete on success, or nil if not found; *not* the modified array). To simplify your code, just use [reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject)

```
finaltext = totaltext.reject{|sentence| nilfacs.any?{|fac| sentence =~ /#{fac}/i } }
```

Comment: Ahhhhh! That would explain it! 
Can I turn {nilfacs} into an array and use it with reject?
I need to be able to reject any sentence that contains even just 1 fac from the nilfac list, which is the part that's had me tearing my hair out for days. And thanks for your time!

Comment: Sure, just make nilfacs an array to begin with (`nilfacs = []`) and append to it instead of doing string concatenation (`nilfacs << fac` instead of `nilfacs = (nilfacs + fac + ' ')`). Then you can use [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) inside the `reject` block.

Comment: Looking forward to trying this tomorrow. Really appreciate the help!